# MIPS instructions to set a register to 1

Tags: assembly, mips

This is a question that has appeared in a few past papers but I cannot find anything about it on the internet.

What six single instruction MIPS can set $v1 to hold the decimal value of 1?

Comment: Please give the references to the papers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Against the common misconception, `li`, `la` or `move` are *not* always just a single instruction.  They're pseudo instructions which assemble to one or more machine-code MIPS instruction.  (`li $v1, 1` will normally assemble to only one instruction because the constant is small, but it will be the same instruction as one of the true MIPS instructions.)  Because of this I guess they don't come as an option.

Here are the instructions that can do such thing

```
addi  $v1, $zero, 1
addiu $v1, $zero, 1
ori   $v1, $zero, 1
xori  $v1, $zero, 1

# these use comparison
slt   $v1, $zero, $31  # the last one can be any non-zero register.  $31 is $ra
slti  $v1, $zero, 1
sltu  $v1, $zero, $31  # the last one can be any non-zero register
sltiu $v1, $zero, 1

# these use memory
lb  $v1, one($zero)
lbu $v1, one($zero)
lh  $v1, one($zero)
lhu $v1, one($zero)
lw  $v1, one($zero)

one: .word 1  #  assuming little-endian MIPS where the lowest-address byte is 1
```

Other possible loads include `lwl` and `lwr` unaligned-word loads, one of those will load the `1` from `one: .word 1`.  But loading from memory requires an address in the low 15 bits or top 15 bits of address-space, which is somewhat unusual.

`$31` aka `$ra` is usually non-zero.  `$sp` is almost always non-zero, but in unusual situations it's possible that some previous code might have set it to zero.  Or perhaps it could be zero after power-on, if we're wanting to set `$v1 = 1` as the first instruction in ROM.

So if we don't count loads (which require extra data at a reachable address) or non-immediate `slt[u]` which require a known non-zero in another register, we have six instructions in classic MIPS I: `addi` / `addiu`, `ori`, `xori`, `sltiu`, and `sltiu`.

When counting with pseudo instructions, `li` and `la` come available too.

Comment: the common mipsconception

Comment: The loads narrower than `lw` assume a little-endian MIPS, like MARS simulates, so the non-zero byte is at the lowest address.  Also that `one:` is in the low 16 bits of address-space, so the `one($zero)` addressing mode can fit in an I-type instruction.  But yes, +1, these are mostly right, except it's `addiu` not `addui`.